# How to Set An HTML SELECT element value to php variable ONSELECT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am Using an HTML dropdown on a page, my requirement is to when i select any value from dropdown, it want to be store in an PHP variable on the same page without submitting form or without refreshing the page.

my code is:

**Script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bank_name").change(function(){

    var data=$(this).val();
    alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        url:"transaction.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: ({"bank_code": data}),
        sucess: function(response){
        console.log("Success");
        alert(data);
    },

    error: function(response){
        console.log("Error");
        alert(data);
    }
    }); 
    <script>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
    $bank_code=$_POST["bank_code"];
    echo "Bank Code is:",$bank_code;
```

it gets the value of selected option and also alerts the value but after alert it doesn't echo the value in PHP.

Comment: Show your html also. And state where you want out-put

Comment: It should be `alert(response);`

Answer (score 2):

You have type error in `success` ,You should remove those () brackets in `data` field to access `$_POST` in php like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bank_name").change(function(){

    var data=$(this).val();
    alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        url:"transaction.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: {bank_code: data),
        success: function(response){
        console.log("Success");
        alert(response);
    },

    error: function(response){
        console.log("Error");
        alert(data);
    }
    }); 
    <script>
```

Comment: i did it but it still does not echo any value

Comment: Those `()` won't afect anything...they will evaluate as the object inside

Comment: HI, naveen i edited my answer, there is a typo error in success,

Comment: The PHP code is placed at the same page after calling this script, but still it don't get any value

Comment: Place the PHP code at a different page else it will load the entire page to ajax

Answer (score 1):

The echo will be received as `response` in the `success` callback

```
$("#bank_name").change(function() {

      var data = $(this).val();
      alert(data);

      $.ajax({
       ....,
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("Success");
          // alert response instead
          alert(response);

        },

       ......
      });
```

Comment: `after alert it doesn't echo the value in PHP.` Seems user want to see the value in pp but not in js

Comment: Exactly, i don't want to refer the response to JS but keep it into PHP variable and echo it into the same php script

Comment: @NaveenK.Sanadhya that's not possible. php only runs on server, not in the browser